# Software and hardware to stop an iPad charging when it reaches ~90-95%

Tags: ipad, battery, charging

I have an iPad with a battery that appears to have degraded and now stops working when it is charged to 100%. (When that happens, I have to keep switching it back on until the battery drops a bit - very annoying.) I don't feel like it's worth replacing the battery or device, but my children do like to use it, so I'm keen to find a programmatic solution.

What I'm thinking of:

1. A plug or charger that I can programme - either to switch off on a timer or, ideally, that can take input from the iPad directly or via the web
2. If the latter is possible, it seems like I can write an app that publishes the battery level of my iPad (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620042-batterylevel)

I know it's an odd question but I'd love to hear ideas/options for Point 1

Comment: It seems weird that the iPad would switch off at 100% but work fine at 95%. Might the power management (i.e. the logic board) be at fault? Have you reset it by holding Sleep and Home buttons for 15 seconds (until you see the Apple logo on restart)?

Comment: Once it reaches 100% it constantly switches itself off until a certain point where it stay son (it's actually not when it goes to 99%, there's a point where it will stay on at 100%). Would the sleep & hold reset differ from the reset its already going through when it goes off and I restart it?

Comment: Would something like a wemo smart plug work?

Comment: Yes, Holding Sleep and Home is different from a normal restart.